# SQL Server Management Studio - First Time Setup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm on Windows 7 and using free version of SQL Server Management Studio. I try connecting to DB server for the first time. I run the program as administrator.

I go to Connect > Database Engine and get a prompt.

```
Server name: (local)
Authentication: Windows Authentication
User name (greyed out): PC\ABC
Password (greyed out):
```

Click Connect and I get:

> Cannot connect to (local). Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

I'm reading MSDN for the past hour which is of course very frustrating and it makes me want to pull my hair out.

Comment: Have you installed a local SQL Server; or are you trying to connect to a remote one. If local; check services to see if its running.

Comment: Please move this question to superuser.com. Do you actually have a SQL Server installed? If so, which one, with which setup? Don't amend the question here, ask it with these additional details on superuser.

Answer (score 2):

to prevent further loss of hair: when you use the free Sql server, called SqlServer Express, the server field needs to be this:

.\SqlExpress

the . is shorthand for local, and the \SqlExpress is the instance name. Bit of an advanced topic, you can run mulitiple SqlServers each having their own name.

more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/e791233e-f805-48b9-82cb-c19da03fbe61/

Good luck with Sql!

Comment: Wow, managed finally thanks to you and JNK. Really this server name would be additional hair loss.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the free SQL Management Studio then you are running **SQL Management Studio Express**. Then are you also running the free version of SqlServer, **SqlExpress**?

If so, to connect to **SqlExpress** on your local machine from ssms express, you need to enter the server name as follows: **.\sqlexpress** .

Answer (score 0):

Did you install SQL Server first?

**SQL Server** is what actually runs the database.

**SQL Server Management Studio** connects to an instance of SQL Server.  If you dont have the server there's nothing to manage.

[Here is a link to the install page from Microsoft.](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a SQL Server installed locally? That's what having `(local)` in the `Server Name` field means - try to connect to the *local* SQL server.

If not, you need to put in the name of an existing SQL Server.

SQL Server Management Studio is a tool to connect to and manage SQL Server instances, it is not the SQL Server itself.